# taRMDistribution - Account does not exist for Account Index (DSTINDX)

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

I'm working with eConnect and trying to send over a transaction.  If I send just the transaction then it shows up in Dynamics GP as I would expect and creates the transaction with a default sales distribution.

[image: transaction]

[image: distribution]

If I try and add distributions I get the error:

Error Number = 1341 Stored Procedure= taRMDistribution Error Description = Account does not exist for Account Index (DSTINDX)
Node Identifier Parameters: taRMDistribution

Here is a sample of my xml:

```html
<eConnect xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <RMTransactionType>
    <eConnectProcessInfo xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRequesterTrxDisabler_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taUpdateCreateCustomerRcd xsi:nil="true" />
    <taCreateCustomerAddress_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRMCommissions_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRMTransactionTaxInsert_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRMDistribution_Items>
      <taRMDistribution>
        <RMDTYPAL>1</RMDTYPAL>
        <DOCNUMBR>b5fad6df-2</DOCNUMBR>
        <CUSTNMBR>MYTESTCUSTOMER</CUSTNMBR>
        <DISTTYPE>9</DISTTYPE>
        <DistRef>60100-002-010</DistRef>
        <CRDTAMNT>100</CRDTAMNT>
      </taRMDistribution>
      <taRMDistribution>
        <RMDTYPAL>1</RMDTYPAL>
        <DOCNUMBR>b5fad6df-2</DOCNUMBR>
        <CUSTNMBR>MYTESTCUSTOMER</CUSTNMBR>
        <DISTTYPE>9</DISTTYPE>
        <DistRef>60100-002-010</DistRef>
        <CRDTAMNT>472</CRDTAMNT>
      </taRMDistribution>
    </taRMDistribution_Items>
    <taAnalyticsDistribution_Items xsi:nil="true" />
    <taRMTransaction>
      <RMDTYPAL>1</RMDTYPAL>
      <DOCNUMBR>b5fad6df-2</DOCNUMBR>
      <DOCDATE>4/8/2021</DOCDATE>
      <BACHNUMB>b5fad6df-2</BACHNUMB>
      <CUSTNMBR>MYTESTCUSTOMER</CUSTNMBR>
      <DOCAMNT>572</DOCAMNT>
      <SLSAMNT>572</SLSAMNT>
    </taRMTransaction>
    <taMdaUpdate_Items xsi:nil="true" />
  </RMTransactionType>
</eConnect>
```

I'm not quite sure what I haven't done.  The error indicates that I need to supply a DSTINDX but I don't know where to find this.  Everything I searched seems to indicate that if I add distribution items I need to supply an account number but I'm not sure where to find this.

I was able to use eConnectOut and find the customer info but there doesn't seem to be any account info in the results.  At this point I'm a bit stumped.

Thanks,

Brian

Answer (score 0):

To solve this I added RMARAC to eConnect_Out_Setup for DOCTYPE ='Customer'.  This gave me the value I needed for DSTINDX.  I used the below link for reference.

[eConnect Customer Requester Document–Missing ShipToName field](http://timwappat.info/post/2015/12/22/eConnect-Customer-Requester-Document-No-ShipToName-field)

Answer (score 0):

Look in GL00101 and GL00105 to find the account index for account segments

Comment: This answer could be improved by adding an explanation how this solves the problem presented in the question.